# I have an issue with React Hook called inside a callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, typescript, eslint

This is my current code

```
export default function InteractableAreasList(): JSX.Element {
  useTownController();
  const activeConversationAreas = useActiveConversationAreas();

  return (
    <Box>
      <Heading as='h2' fontSize='l'>
        Active Areas:
      </Heading>
      {activeConversationAreas.length === 0 ? (
        <>No active conversation areas</>
      ) : (
        activeConversationAreas
          .filter(area => area.isActive())
          .sort((a1, a2) => a1.id.localeCompare(a2.id))
          .map(area => {
            const friendlyName = useInteractableAreaFriendlyName(area);
            const occupants = useInteractableAreaOccupants(area);
            return (
              <Box key={area.id}>
                <Heading as='h3' fontSize='m'>
                  {area.id}: {friendlyName}
                </Heading>
                <UnorderedList>
                  {occupants.map(occupant => (
                    <ListItem key={occupant.id}>
                      <PlayerName player={occupant} />
                    </ListItem>
                  ))}
                </UnorderedList>
              </Box>
            );
          })
      )}
    </Box>
  );
}
```

And I am having two error messages when i run the command `npm run lint`.

```
 39:34  error  React Hook "useInteractableAreaFriendlyName" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function 
 react-hooks/rules-of-hooks



40:31  error  React Hook "useInteractableAreaOccupants" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function    
 react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
```

I tried to write a helper function so that, but in the end, i find out i am still called the helper function inthe callback

Comment: Please provide actual code! not some image.

Comment: https://react.dev/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning says "Do not call Hooks inside conditions or loops.". Map is a loop.

Comment: Make a subcomponent for each "box", so your map looks something like `.map(area => <MyBox area={area}>)` - put the rest of the map code in the MyBox component so each MyBox runs 2 hook calls.